# UPDATE INTO from an INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below that works great for copying data from a table on one database (origin table) into a table in another database (copy to table).   Is there a way to change this to an update so as the data changes on the origin table, I can update the data on the copy to table?

```
INSERT INTO
    [ROCKFTINFO].[ShopDatabase].[dbo].[ref.Card]
    (
        REF.[Card_ID]
        , REF.[FirstName]
        , REF.[LastName]
    )
SELECT
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(CRH.FirstName)) AS [FirstName],
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(CRH.LastName)) AS [LastName],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CRD.CardNumber)) AS [Card_ID]
FROM 
    CardHolder AS CRH INNER JOIN
    Card AS CRD ON CRH.RecordID = CRD.CardHolderID
WHERE 
    (CRD.Deleted = 0) AND (CRH.Deleted = 0) AND (CRD.CardNumber > 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Update would look like the following

```
update r set
  r.FirstName = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DecryptByKey(CRH.FirstName)),
   r.LastName = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DecryptByKey(CRH.LastName))
from CardHolder crh 
join Card crd on crd.CardHolderID = CRH.RecordID 
join ROCKFTIFO.ShopDatabase.dbo.[ref.Card] r on r.Card_Id = crd.Card_Id
where <condition>
```

Notes

- You should always specifiy a *length* for (n)varchar.
- Assumes the join criteria is using `Card_Id` - I have left off the *trim* functions here - if you require it then use it however to effectively join the data needs to match - using a function on the data makes it unsargable and will force a table/index scan, you should if necessary be sanitising the source data.
- `ref.card` including a name-separator in a column name is a poor choice and confusing for anyone maintaining the system, plus forces you to always have to delimit it. What's wrong with an underscore like used for `Card_Id`?

Comment: Stu thank you very much for the update and the notes.  I made the changes you recommended, but I still haven't figured it out.  Below is what I'm trying.  My plan was to run this on the server with the data, and update the data on my other server that I added as a linked server.

Comment: OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY WPEnctSymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE WPEnctCertificate
update r set
  r.FirstName = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DecryptByKey(CRH.FirstName)),
   r.LastName = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DecryptByKey(CRH.LastName))
from CardHolder crh 
join Card crd on crd.CardHolderID = CRH.RecordID 
join [ROCKFTINFO].[SHOPDATA].[dbo.Card_Data] r on r.Card_Id = crd.Card_Id